# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: component.canDeactivate is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this error when I build my *CanDeactivateGuard* .

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: component.canDeactivate is not a function

I want to make my *CanDeactivateGuard* reusable, so it should be generic.

therefor I've built an abstract class which called *ComponentCanDeactivate* and then extended it in the *TreeCanDeactivateGuard*.

The *CanDeactivateGuard* should then implement the interface *CanDeactivate*.

My Code:

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {

  public abstract canDeactivate(): boolean;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
        $event.returnValue = true;
    }
}
```

}

The *TreeCanDeactivateGuard* :

```
import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from './canDeactivate/component-can-deactivate';
import { NodeService } from '../tree/node.service';


export abstract class TreeCanDeactivateGuard extends ComponentCanDeactivate {

    constructor(private _nodeService: NodeService) {
    super();
    }

    public canDeactivate(): boolean {
      if (this._nodeService.treeChangesTracer === false) {
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
      }
}
```

}

The *CanDeactivateGuard*:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
    import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from './component-can-deactivate';

    @Injectable()
    export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {

        constructor() { }
         canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean {

            if (!component.canDeactivate()) {
                if (confirm('You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost.')) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Routes Module :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: TreeComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] , runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `TreeCanDeactivateGuard`? It isn't referenced anywhere in your code.

You don't want `TreeCanDeactivateGuard` to extend `ComponentCanDeactivate`, you want `TreeComponent` to extend `ComponentCanDeactivate` instead.

Make any component extend `ComponentCanDeactivate` and implement `canDeactivate` then you'll be able to use the generic guard `CanDeactivateGuard` for it.

You could also replace:

```
if (confirm('You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost.')) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

With: `return confirm('You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost.');`

Comment: Hi, TreeCanDeactivateGuard did refrenced it the second part :)
But anyway you gave me the solution :D now it works and I dont need the TreeCanDeactivateGuard since I extended the ComponentCanDeactivate in my base Tree Component ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an absctact method directly through abstract class. Had to do it through child class. Like

```
     canDeactivate(component: TreeCanDeactivateGuard): boolean {

        if (!component.canDeactivate()) {
```

Comment: it does not work! I just tried to log the component object and realized that it is converted into object of type (TreeComponent) at runtime. so whatever the type is it would be anyway at runtime converted.